# Angular 1.5 Expected array but received: 0 when using filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a table, it works fine when I display data, this is the code

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in sd.data track by $index | orderBy: syscode">
  <td>{{($index>0 && sd.data[$index].syscode === sd.data[$index-1].syscode) ? '' : value.syscode}}</td>
  <td>{{value.out_signal_id}}</td>
  <td class="text-center no-wrapping">{{value.sig_epoch_utc}}</td>
  <td class="text-center ">{{value.num_of_signals}}</td>
  <td class="text-center no-wrapping">{{value.status_code}}</td>
  <td class="text-center no-wrapping">{{value.status_note}}</td>


 <tr >
```

My issue is that when I use 'orderBy:' as a filter, I get this error

```
`Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array` but received: 0
```

I am not sure why, I have checked other questions similar to this, but those didn't answer my question. Any feedback will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Track by should be **always** at the end and you miss apices so this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in sd.data track by $index | orderBy: syscode">
```

should be:

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in sd.data | orderBy: 'syscode' track by $index">
```

Comment: sorry updating I didn't see the track by

Answer (score 1):

This exact scenario is covered in [the docs for ngRepeat (see the note at the bottom of the section)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates). Basically, the `track by` needs to be the last thing in your expression.

```
value in sd.data | orderBy: 'syscode' track by $index
```